# Bluefruit ezlink is not accepting my sketch

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have recently purchased both a new Arduino Uno and a new Bluefruit EZLink shield.  I am able to upload sketches to the unit via USB (with the selector set to "soft").  I can pair with the unit and use the serial monitor to send data back and forth (with the selector set to "direct").  What I can not seem to do is upload a sketch to the unit over the bluetooth link as described in the features for this shield.

The response from avrdude that I get is this:

```
avrdude: Version 5.11.1, compiled on Apr 28 2013 at 18:46:46
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/home/growlf/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/rfcomm0
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I have tried setting the baud rate to 9600 via upload over commandline, but that does not change the response much.  It almost seems like the shield is not resetting, but I am not sure.  I *do* see the lights for TX/RX flicker rapidly for a moment on both the shield and the Uno itself, indicating the sketch was sent and some sort of response was given.

I have also (as I have seen suggested in my Googling) pressed the reset button just before and just after transmission - no difference.

Any suggestions or pointers on how to upload using this shield are very welcome and apreciated.

Comment: The timing on pressing the reset button is tricky. What I do is hold down reset, press upload on the arduino IDE, and as soon as the arduino IDE status changes from 'compiling' to 'uploading' release the reset button. You only have a 1 - 2 second window.

Comment: This is just an fyi. Keep an eye on the [Arduino proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino).

Comment: I agree on the Area51 proposal, and am already committed :)  Thank you!  The thnig is, supposedly, according to the hype/docs this shield does not require the pressing of the reset key anyway.  It is "a Bluetooth shield that can change baud rates on the fly and toggle the DTR pin as desired" - see it [here](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1628#Description)

Comment: Looks like it may be a bug in the design after all.  Adafruit is looking into a solution and I will post the answer once they have it.  The concept of the thing is awesome - one connection for both data AND programming.  I just hope it is not too good to be true after all.

Comment: FYI: That's the third or fourth Arduino proposal. The preceding ones have all failed after launch. I'm not trying to be a naysayer, but history does tend to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a Bluefruit EZlink shield (but I would very much like one).  I use a commodity bluetooth adapter

Make sure you've got the right baud rate - AVR 328P devices generally default to 57600, and ATMega 1280/2560 devices default to 115,200 IIRC.

I've had similar problems, though.   My advice to you is to download and compile the latest version of avrdude, which fixed my problems initially.   Versions 6.0.1 or so will keep retrying the connection, which gives you multiple chances to hit the reset button.

Recently, though, Fedora 19 quit allowing me to upload with bluetooth.   I was able to fix the problem by patching avrdude to retry sending data if the error code is ENOTCONN (107) "Transport endpoint is not connected"

So - if you still have trouble uploading after compiling avrdude, then try my patch at:
https://savannah.nongnu.org/patch/?8272

Comment: First off - thank you for responding!  
I will attempt this during next week (I have had to leave this project temporarily, but am circling back).  I suspect that you have the answer right there. From everything I have seen so far, this rings very true to me.  Once I have verified it, I will mark this as answered and point the Adafruit forum posts to this as well.